# Passing the value from a checked radio button into a python GET function for evaluation

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, html

I am trying to pass the value of the selected (checked) radio button into a `GET` function I later want to evaluate in Python that is used to display an alert.

If I include `.checked` in my variable definition nothing is passed, without it, only the first element is passed.

I am guessing my problem is either in the variable definition

```
let genera = document.querySelector("#myform input[type='radio']");
```

or

in the passing of the argument to the GET function.

```
$.get('/test?genera=' + genera.value,
```

I appreciate the advise.

Thanks in advance

Here is a part of my code

**index.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="genera" name="genera" placeholder="Genera" type="text">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Play" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    let genera = document.querySelector("#myform input[type='radio']");

    document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = function() {
            $.get('/test?genera=' + genera.value, function(data) {
            if (data==true){
                    alert($("#myform input[type='radio']:checked").val()+" is correct");
                    return true;
                }
            else{
                    alert($("#myform input[type='radio']:checked").val()+ " is wrong answer, better luck next time!");
                    return true;
                }
            })
    };
</script>
```

**applycation.py file**

```
from flask import jsonify


selection = request.args.get("genera")

cont = db.execute("SELECT * FROM contributions WHERE id_contribution = :id_contribution AND genera= :genera",
                  id_contribution=active,
                  genera=selection)
if len(cont) != 0:
    return jsonify(True)

else:
    return jsonify(False)
```

---

Solved by directly referencing the checked radio button in the get function arguments

```
$.get('/test?genera=' + $("#myform input[type='radio']:checked").val(), function(data) {
```

Still do not know why it did not take it as a variabe

Comment: do your radio buttons have the same names?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I think you are missing `checked` in this line `document.querySelector("#myform input[type='radio']")`

Comment: Have you tried cutting down the source code to debug the issue? Maybe something as simple as `print request.args.get("genera")` in your python "Comment everything else out" and use `console.log(data);` / `alert(data);` in your `ajax` get request and comment out your `if()` condition? This will help check you are getting the expected data from your request.

Comment: radio buttons are generated by a for loop                                                         
 {% for options in options %}
            <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="selection" required="required"
                    name="selection" value="{{ options["genera"] }}">{{ options["genera"] }}
                </label>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

Comment: Without checked (let genera = document.querySelector("#myform input[type='radio'])) I get the first element of the radio buttons. With checked (let genera = document.querySelector("#myform input[type='radio']:checked");) I get (index):98 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at HTMLInputElement.document.querySelector.onclick ((index):98)